# How can I store a data each 10ms in Firebase?

Tags: php, python, mysql, amazon-web-services, firebase

I'm working on a real-time application. The app consists in getting accelerations for the environment with a digital accelerometer, which is connected to a computing and wireless unit (sensor node).

The sensor node is sampling a signal between 0-50 Hz, it means the node must send out at least 100 samples per second (Niquist Theorem) to the coordinator (Raspbeey pi 3) which is connected to internet and the income data is stored in a database in Firebase.

Then, someone should be able to look at the behaviour of the accelerometer in "real-time" from a Android / Web app.

The problem is when I take a look into my database, the maximum amoung of data that my database is storing per second are only 6 data, for that reason it is impossible to reach my goal.

I'm new in database and those kind of things and I have some questions:

1. How can I store a data each 10ms in Firebase?
2. I've read something about php, mysql, apache and AWS, Can I finish my proyect using any of those previous tools and How?
3. I read that Firebase allows you retrive data in a stream way but I didn't find out any about storing o writing data in a streaming way. Is it possible in Firebase?
4. Web sockets could be the solution?

   ```
   import requests
   import time
   import requests
   import json
   from random import randrange
   from datetime import datetime
   firebase_url = 'https://aplicacionfirebase-683c2.firebaseio.com/'  
   while 1:
       try:
           hora =  datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]
           ace1 =randrange(1, 50)
           ace2 = randrange(10, 50)
           ace3 = randrange(20, 90)
           data = {'hora':hora,'ace1' : ace1, 'ace2':ace2,'ace3':ace3}
           resultado = requests.post(firebase_url +  '/Aceleraciones.json', data=json.dumps(data))
           time.sleep(0.01)
       except:
           print "Ocurrio un error"
   ```

[image_test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMBMl.png)

Comment: `sleep` is not always as accurate as you think. If you need precision you may need another way to do this.

Comment: While this is a very interesting question, I think it may be going the wrong direction for a solution. Obviously there is precision involved and  wireless connections and the internet provide in-preceice timeframes to to stream granular time sensitive data. To use Firebase, disassociate the timestamp/data from the FB push i.e. obtain 100 samples of data and then push that timestamp and data to FB. Rinse, repeat. That will result in a node key and child data (key_x/timestamp: data_1 and key_x/timestamp: data_1. Once that data is written, users apps will receive that data via childAdded events.